# calculate difference between Rows in R by setting specific target date

Tags: r

I am new at R, my df is as the following and I would like to set my bench comparison date as 2020/02/01, compare the results against the row with this date:
Here is my data frame,  I want to be able to genearte the Diff Column with R

| DATE | FRUIT | LOCATION | VALUE | DIFF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010-01-01 | Apple | USA | 2 | -2 |
| 2010-02-01 | Apple | USA | 4 | 0 |
| 2020-11-01 | Apple | USA | 100 | 96 |
| 2020-12-01 | Apple | USA | 54 | 50 |
| 2010-01-01 | Apple | China | 0 | -4 |
| 2010-02-01 | Apple | China | 4 | 0 |
| 2020-11-01 | Apple | China | 40 | 36 |
| 2020-12-01 | Apple | China | 44 | 40 |
| 2010-01-01 | Banana | USA | 1 | -1 |
| 2010-02-01 | Banana | USA | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-11-01 | Banana | USA | 12 | 10 |
| 2020-12-01 | Banana | USA | 13 | 11 |
| 2010-01-01 | Banana | China | 0 | -100 |
| 2010-02-01 | Banana | China | 100 | 0 |
| 2020-11-01 | Banana | China | 130 | 30 |
| 2020-12-01 | Banana | China | 145 | 45 |

Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide the dataframes as the output of `dput` so that we can easily replicate them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you can do :

```
library(dplyr)
compare_date <- as.Date('2010-02-01')

df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
  group_by(Fruit, Metric) %>%
  mutate(Diff = Value - Value[match(compare_date, Date)]) -> result

result
```

Comment: Thank you!  The code makes sense, but when I run it.. this is the error message  "Error in UseMethod("mutate") : no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "function""

Comment: @user15032839 You need to change `df` with the name of your dataframe.

Comment: thanks again!  I think it worked.  but for some reason, the column Diff was not created...

Comment: You need to check `result` for output.

Comment: In the last line instead of assigning it to `-> result` assign it to `-> df`.